# Why there is no UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in my security filter chain?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have defined the `securityFilterChain` like below

```java
http
                .cors().configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() {
                    @Override
                    public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
                        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                        //todo: this should be set as environment variable
                        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost"));
                        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
                        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                        config.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization")); //todo: what does this ean?
                        config.setMaxAge(3600L);
                        return config;
                    }
                })
                .and().csrf().disable()//todo: set csrf() in prod: ignoreingRequestMatch
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll() //authorized all the target here
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) // do not store any state

                .and().authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

In the last line, I added `jwtAuthFilter` before `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class` as was shown in a tutorial.
However, when I enable the logging of filter chain proxy as below
`logging.level.org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy=DEBUG`

here is the logging

```
Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  LogoutFilter
  JwtAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]
```

Here is js my questions.

1. Why `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class` is not in the filter chain?
2. Is the order of the filter chain printed on the logging correct? if it is not correct where can I find the correct order?

Thanks!

I wnat to know the correct order of security filter chain

Comment: The tutorial you are following is displaying bad practices. Its not recommended to hand out jwts to browsers, and use them as sessions. There is a reason as to why that type of authentication is not implemented in spring.

Comment: is it a good practice to keep them in a cache like Redis? when validation, check both jwt and device info.

Comment: maybe i didn't get the point, could you explain it in more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is typically added to the filter chain automatically when you enable formLogin().

1. when you enable "http.formLogin()", you'll see that the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter will be automatically added to the security filter chain.
2. your JwtAuthFilter is added before the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, which appears to be the correct filter chain order.

Example code

```
http.formLogin().loginPage("/login")
```

You can read about security filter chain here.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-print-filters

Comment: how does spring security where to put my custom filter if UserNameAuthenticationFilter is not in the list?

Comment: First, if you look at the FilterComparator class in Spring Security, it stores the filter names and order in a filterToOrder Map. And when you use addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class), you register customFilter by setting -1 in the order position of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
In this case, since UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is the default filter of Spring Security, its order is defined, so even if UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter does not exist in your filter chain list, SpringSecurity will compare the order and determine its position